# understanding the grammar of "XをYに"

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

> 兄さんをエサにホムンクルスを引っ張り出します

Is there an implied verb after に, or not? Is this sentence more along the lines of the situation when you have two verbs connected with the ～て form, or is it more along the lines of "兄さんをエサに" being an element of the verb 引っ張り出す in the same way that ホムンクルスを is?

Could you replace に with として here? If so, how would it compare with the sentence using に? If not, why not?

I know I asked a lot of questions; just address whichever ones make the most sense.

[image: niisan wo esa ni]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track about the missing verb. The missing verb can be して. But you do not need to change the particle. Just add the missing verb: `兄さんをエサにして`. Using `と` here is unnatural. I think `として` can be used as "as if", implying that it is not actually it. In `兄さんをエサにして...を引っ張り出す`, the brother is actually treated as bait, so `に` should be used. In `兄さんをエサとして扱う` or `兄さんをエサとみなす`, there is implication that the brother is not actually bait, so `と` is used.

Comment: So I guess you have can't have more than one direct object per verb. That's good to know. :)

Comment: @dotnetN00b In Japanese, you cannot have more than one accusative phrase (Not the same as direct object). In Korean, you can.

Comment: We really need a wiki on what all of these grammatical terms mean :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `して` is implied after the `に`.  The robot ホムンクルス seems to be saying that he'll make the guy (兄さん) like bait (`エサ`) and pull him along (and won't let him die).