# に particles with no attaching verbs

Tags: particle-に

> 口下手で料理好きの父親を主人公**に**、家庭や会社の人間ドラマをほのぼのと描いた漫画 「クッキングパパ」が昨年末、「週刊モーニング」（講談社）で連載千回を迎えた。

What is the first に particle doing?

Comment: Reference: http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110008005817

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5690/understanding-the-grammar-of-x%E3%82%92y%E3%81%AB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This に means "with" or "using".

AをBに = "With A as B" or "using A as B"

口下手で料理好きの父親を主人公に modifies 描いた = "drawn with a 口下手で料理好きの父親 as its hero"