Use of を followed by に without a verb
This is a sentece from the 3rd chapter of 新中級から上級への日本語

口べたで料理好きの父親を主人公に、家庭や会社の人間ドラマをほのぼのと描いた漫画「クッキングパパ」が昨年末、「週刊モーニング」で連載千回を迎えた。

What I don't get is the を主人公に part. If I were to take a guess, I would say it means something like 'the clumsy father that loves cooking made protagonist (...)'. But even if I were right, I would not know how the grammar works. What does it mean?

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73082/meaning-of-%e3%82%92%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e3%82%92%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e3%82%92%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e3%82%92%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e3%82%92%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f-%e3%82%92%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f

@user3856370:  Yep, that what is was gonna say.  Typically the same meaning as omitting 「して」.

You should think of this particular combination as "with ... as ...", with を corresponding to "with", and に corresponding to "as".

[口べたで料理好きの父親を][主人公に]
with the inarticulate, gourmet-loving father as the main character

This whole phrase is a modifier of 漫画「クッキングパパ」"the manga 'Cooking Papa'".

It can sometimes also be understood as "with ... in/at ..." as in 大きな決意を胸に試合に参加した. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82369/902
